# Haskell: What is the difference between (+1) and (\x->x+1)?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Is there a difference between these two functions?

ghct says:

```
Prelude> :t (+1)
(+1) :: Num a => a -> a
Prelude> :t \x->x+1
\x->x+1 :: Num a => a -> a
```

**But**

When I used (+1) syntax in this piece of code:

```
data B = B { 
    pos :: Int, 
    cells :: [Int] 
} deriving (Show)

createB :: Int -> B
createB n = B 0 (take n $ repeat 0)

size :: B -> Int
size b = length $ cells b

get_curr :: B -> Int
get_curr b = (cells b) !! (pos b)

apply :: (Int -> Int) -> B -> B
apply f b = let n = pos b
                h = take n $ cells b       -- head
                t = drop (n + 1) $ cells b -- tail
                in B n $ h ++ [f (get_curr b)] ++ t

-- ...
eval :: [Char] -> StateT B IO ()
eval [] = return ()
eval (x:xs) = do
                b <- get

                put $ case x of
                        '+'         -> apply (+1) b
                        '-'         -> apply (-1) b
                        '>'         -> fwd b
                        '<'         -> back b
                        otherwise   -> b
                -- ...
```

prelude (as well as compiler) said:

```
> :load BrainFuck.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling BrainFuck        ( BrainFuck.hs, interpreted )

BrainFuck.hs:49:40:
    No instance for (Num (Int -> Int))
      arising from the literal `1'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num (Int -> Int))
    In the expression: 1
    In the first argument of `apply', namely `(- 1)'
    In the expression: apply (- 1) b
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

What am I doing wrong?
sorry if code is not-so-cool (full source here: https://github.com/nskeip/bf/blob/a755b2d27292593d63fe1e63c2a6e01cebc73520/BrainFuck.hs)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This code:

```
(-1)
```

... doesn't mean the same thing as this code:

```
\ x -> x - 1
```

`-` is a special case in Haskell; it is the only **prefix operator** in the language. When you write `(-1)`, you get "negative one" which is a number, and not "subtract one" which is a function.

You should use `subtract 1` to get what you need.

Comment: You can also use `pred`, but note that `pred minBound` will throw an exception while `subtract 1 minBound` will wrap around.

Answer (score 11):

Your problem is not with `(+1)`, it's with `(-1)`:

```
Prelude> :t (-1)
(-1) :: Num a => a
```

[`-1` is a number!](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Section_of_an_infix_operator) Try with `apply (\x -> x-1) b` or `apply (subtract 1) b`.

Comment: damn! exactly) but why (+1) is not?)))

Comment: Because you don't *need* a unary/prefix `+` and thus there is none.

Comment: See the link to "Section of an infix operator"

Comment: Because `1` is already a positive number. `(-1)` is defined to be a number, because you need to be able to write down negative numbers somehow. It's already taken care of for positives by just not using a sign in front.

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference between `(+1)` and `\x -> x + 1` and if you look closely, `(+1)` isn't what's causing your error. `(-1)` is. And that's because unlike `(+1)`, `(-1)` is not an operator section, it's negative one.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `subtract` the decrement expression can be written directly also as `(+(-1))` .